# Dark fantasy book where a farm was attacked by a necromancer and a farmer accused of incest

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

It’s so dumb cause I’ve just got bits and pieces of the first book. Like I remember they were a farming family and her family was killed by a necromancer (?) but then she and her brother were nearly killed by the village on charges of incest which weren’t true. There was a villainess who carried spiders in her womb, and then there was a plague forest. And that’s all I remember, I just want to read it again.

It was a paperback, it was at least 15 years ago that I read it, and it was part of a series. I don’t remember how magic works in the story. I remember there being no modern setting or modern technology. I feel like it was components though.

Comment: “I just want to read it again” — get the kind of warm Christmas glow that only womb-spiders can provide!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be thinking of one of the books from James Clemens' [The Banned and the Banished series](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1177331.Wit_ch_Storm), likely either [Wit'ch Fire](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/872109.Wit_ch_Fire) or [Wit'ch Storm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBUc1m.jpg). The series centres on a girl named Elena Morinstal, who has a brother named Joach, and lives on her parents' orchard in a valley. Her parents are subsequently murdered, and she learns she has magical powers. The second book in the series, *Wit'ch Storm*, apparently features a spider-birthing villainess, named Virani (pictured on the cover below).

[image]

Comment: That’s it!! Thank you, thank you! 

Comment: Out of curiosity, was this a series you were already familiar with? Or if not, how did you find it?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I found a reddit thread discussing the series when I searched for "book series girl witch spiders womb" on DuckDuckGo.

Comment: @LogicDictates: 
As one does...